# Devexpress. Как добавить в toolbox элемент richTextBox?

Tags: c#, devexpress

**Используется**

- Visual Studio 2015
- Devexpress 15.1

В **toolbox** отсутствует элемент **richTextBox** для **Devexpress**.

**Вопрос:**
Как добавить в **toolbox** элемент **richTextBox**?
Или для **Devexpress** отдельный **richTextBox** не предполагается?

Answer (score 1):

Для [RichEditControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/6975/Controls-and-Libraries/Rich-Text-Editor/Fundamentals/RichEditControl) в панели элементов при установке создается отдельная группа «DX.15.1 Rich Text Editor».

Если этой группы нет, то, возможно, содержимое панели было изменено. Возможные пути решения:

1. Утилита DevExpress. В Visual Studio в меню DevExpress должен быть пункт «Repair Toolbox», который восстановливает элементы DevExpress.
2. Добавить компонент вручную. Нажать правой кнопкой на панель и выбрать пункт «Choose Items...». Найти в списке компонентов RichEditControl в сборке DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.